# Font rendering with dual monitors

Tags: gnome, emacs, fonts, multiple-monitors

I use Debian with GNOME on a laptop with an external VGA monitor.

Emacs has a problem with font rendering. As you can see in the image below, some characters are "transformed" when the cursor is next to them.

For instance, the letter "K" isn't rendered properly when the cursor is next to it:

[image]

As soon as the cursor moves, "K" is rendered properly:

[image]

This strange font rendering only happens when I'm working in dual screen - when I'm using both the laptop and VGA monitors at the same time. If I'm using only one of them there is no problem with the font rendering.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this problem?

I would like to add that this only occurs when "Hinting" is set to "Full".

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem when I run emacs on gnome shell or its derivatives (cinnamon and mate). Although it hasn't completely fixed the problem for me, setting column number mode to true has [helped some people](http://ubuntu-users.livejournal.com/307544.html?thread=2193240#t2193240):

```
(setq-default column-number-mode t)
```